# Store changeable (on runtime) lists in GSettings?

Tags: python, ubuntu, settings, pygobject, canonical-quickly

I want to store changeable list in GSettings (the list is the contents of a GtkComboBoxText - how to get all of it, btw?). By changeable I mean, that it might need changing on runtime. What is the best way to do it?

Of course I can just concatenate the list into a string with some specific separator, but that seems ugly. Is it possible to use "choices", for example?

I use python 2.7 + PyGObobject, the programme is for Ubuntu and is developed using Quickly.